# How to remove extra spaces on the section

Tags: html, css, position

I'm trying to removed the extra space underneath the The place to book your radio, podcast and voice over appointments.[enter image description here][1] My code is underneath.

section class="colored-section" id="title">

```
    <div class="container-fluid">



      <!-- Nav Bar -->

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">



        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">

          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="row">


      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
        <img class="title-image" src="images/Stephan's Notes.Rs3.1-01.png" alt="logo-mockup">
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
        <h1 class="big-heading">The place to book your radio, podcast and voice over appointments.</h1>
      </div>

      </div>

    </div>

</section>
```

CSS Section

```
.title-image {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 30%;
    left: 40%;

.big-heading {
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Montserrat-Black";
    right: 700px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    top: 100px;
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if I got it, but you can try to inspect the elements and check the margin of these BootStrap's classes...